# Calling Handler From Different Domain and Sending Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making ajax  call  from cross  domain  and getting Error::

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://*********:8080/ActiveDirectiveActionRepulsionController.ashx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://********' is therefore not allowed access.

My  Ajax call is

```
var url = http://********:8080/ActiveDirectiveActionRepulsionController.ashx
 $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: url,
                                async:true,
                                data: { "REQUESTTYPE": 1, "USERNAME": forgotUsername.val() },
                                success: function (result) {
                                    if (result == "Username you provided  doesnot exist") {
                                        updateTips(result);
                                    }
                                    else if(result == "Sucessfull") {
                                        $(".validateTips").text("All form fields are required.");
                                        $("#Forgot-password").dialog("close");
                                        setDialogMessage("Your password has been send to your registered email id.");
                                        $("#dialog-forgot-message").dialog("open");
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                        alert('Time out error.');
                                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                                    }
                                }

                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a request to another domain you must set but a CORS policy on that domain.

At the very least you have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header; a complete solution is a little more involved.

I see this same question pop up often, so I have a [full answer on my blog](http://fritsvancampen.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/cross-site-origin-requests-aka-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

Comment: how to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" i am new to this

Comment: You're using ASP, I'm not too familiar with that, my blog covers the solution in PHP, I'm sure it's similar for ASP.